# Passbook pass can not be installed

Tags: certificate, ios6, pki, passbook

I created a pass that worked fine with iOS 6 beta 4, but now can not be installed with iOS 6 final release. The pass shows fine on the device but gives the following error in Console.app when tapping on Add:

> 10/10/2012 11:39:56.460 passd[47329]: Invalid data error reading card pass.com.test.example/serial_number. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.

Since I know the certificate, passTypeIdentifier and teamIdentifier are right, it can only be the certificate chain. I have the WWDR certificate installed on the computer used for exporting the pass certificate, why do I get this error? Is the certificate chain not being exported?

We are generating the passes using [PHP PKPass](https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass).

I am using a In-House license and distributing to one of the registered devices if that matters.

Comment: As far as I can tell, every Passbook framework has this issue - I'm having the same problem with the Ruby gem `passifier`, and here's the issue for [dotnet-passbook](https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook/issues/3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was indeed the WWDR certificate not being added to the manifest.json signature. And this is actually solved in the latest version of PHP PKPass (So much time wasted investigating this instead of just checking if it was fixed on the newest version :S)